# How to change a list outside function without a = function(a,b)?

Tags: python, function, return

```
l = ["1","2"]
e = "3"
def add(e,s):
    s = s + [e]
    return s
add(e,l)
print(l)
```

Why doesn’t it print `['1','2','3']`?

Comment: replace `s = s + [e]` with `s += [e]`  This modifies `s` in place instead of creating a new list.

Answer (score 3):

`s + [e]` is a new list. You assign this to the variable `s` in the function `add`.

This variable is not the same as the variable `l` in your outer code. It starts out referring to the same object, but you change that when you assign a different object to `s`.

Probably what you want to do is change the contents of the object to which `s` refers, rather than making `s` refer to a different object:

```
s.append(e)
```

This means that `s` and `l` will continue to refer to the same object, and that object is modified.

Comment: And the `return` would be unnecessary.

Comment: Or they could do `s += [e]`.  This modifies in-place so will also give the desired result.

Comment: @SethMMorton: they could, but there's a difficulty with `+=`, which is that it exists for immutable sequences (`tuple`) but doesn't do the same thing as it does for mutable sequences. I wouldn't really want my `add` function to accept a tuple but silently do nothing to it, that's asking for bugs somewhere down the line.

Comment: Using either `+=` or `.append` on a `tuple` raises a `TypeError`.  You are safe from python silently failing in both cases.

Comment: The reason this is true is that `__iadd__` exists for a `list`, but not `tuple`.  You can prove it to yourself with `dir(list)` and `dir(tuple)`.

Comment: @SethMMorton: try it. `a = (1,2); a += (3,); print(a)`. Output is `(1,2,3)`. If a class doesn't have `__iadd__` but does have `__add__` then `x += y` is interpreted the same as `x = x + y`.

Comment: Yup, you're right.  I had tried it earlier but had a typo in my test so misinterpreted the results, hence my stating things that are untrue.